# Sizes of data-type in c and their size in memory

Tags: c, memory, double

How much size is reserved in memory when I declare  `double buf[128 * 1024];` in C?  I'm trying to figure out the relation between size of data-type and how much size is reserved for that data-type variable in memory.

Comment: Try with `sizeof(buf)` and see what happens.

Comment: If it's not global or static, probably stack overflow will happen.

Comment: @andreee No, `sizeof(buf)` is fine. `buf` is not a pointer.

Comment: And remember that, whatever you get, is not generalizable. An other implementation can do something else (though will probably only on significantly different platforms).

Comment: Use `double buf[128 * 1024]; printf("Size: %zu\n", sizeof buf)` or `printf("Size: %lu\n", (unsigned long) sizeof buf);`

Answer (score 0):

> How much size is reserved in memory when I declare  double buf[128 *
>   1024]; in C?

```
double buf[128 * 1024];
```

`buf` is an array and you can use `sizeof(buf);` so that the compiler calculates the number of bytes allocated for your array by using .

`sizeof(double)(Platform dependant) * number of elements in the array(128 * 1024)`